# How to install all rpm dependencies and map local to created YUM repository?

Tags: centos7, rpm, yum

I have a scenario of having yum repository (say named A) with newer version of NodeJS rpm in Centos 7. When I tried to install it ends up in list of dependency error and few rpm packages was not able figure it on own by YUM. So download all the dependency rpm's and placed in created repository. Started to installing  rpm using this command

```
rpm -ivh http-parser
```

Then try to get info of the installed package using this command

```
yum info http-parser
```

Following info is listed

```
Installed Packages
Name        : http-parser
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.7.1
Release     : 8.el7
Size        : 71 k
Repo        : installed
Summary     : HTTP request/response parser for C
URL         : https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser
License     : MIT
Description : This is a parser for HTTP messages written in C. It
            : parses both requests and responses. The parser is
            : designed to be used in performance HTTP
            : applications. It does not make any syscalls nor
            : allocations, it does not buffer data, it can be
            : interrupted at anytime. Depending on your
            : architecture, it only requires about 40 bytes of
            : data per message stream (in a web server that is per
            : connection).
```

My intention of installing this package and map to created custom repository (names as A). But the info command shows it installed over globally "Repo: installed" instead of "Repo: A". I doubted I missed few steps to install dependencies local to created repository. How do I verify whether the package installed and available local to the repository?

I would like to know whether this is the proper way of handling dependency errors in centos package installation?

Any guidance over these are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yum` doesn't remember what repo it was installed from. When you asked `yum` for any info about any packages it knows about named `http-parser`, it told you it knows of the one that is currently installed. It uses the reserved name "installed" for that purpose.